# Calculating difference selected elements pandas dataframe columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Need code logic which checks the mispricing value, and the first time is greater than 6, it would take that time stamp Value and let’s call it “TS1”. It would then check for consecutive m[image]ispricing>6, the first time the mispricing goes from yes to no, take the timestamps on mispricing = no and call it “TS2”.

Then do TS2 - TS1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data={'ts':list(range(1,14)),
                      'mp':[0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0]}) # your data
df.loc[df.mp.diff(1)==1, 'ts1'] = df.ts  # TS1
df.loc[df.mp.diff(1)==-1, 'ts2'] = df.ts  # TS2
df=df[~(df.ts1.isna())|~(df.ts2.isna())] # keep only rows with changes
df.loc[~df.ts2.isna(), 'delta'] = df.ts2 - df.ts1.shift(1)  # TS2-TS1
print (df)

    ts  mp   ts1   ts2  delta
2    3   1   3.0   NaN    NaN
5    6   0   NaN   6.0    3.0
7    8   1   8.0   NaN    NaN
9   10   0   NaN  10.0    2.0
11  12   1  12.0   NaN    NaN
12  13   0   NaN  13.0    1.0
```